# Ordering of sentence with “since"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these two sentences? Is there a big differences? Which one is correct?

> **A**: I have been working on this project since last week.
>
> **B**: Since last week I am working on this project.

Comment: A is correct. B is wrong. You can't follow **since** with the present continuous tense.

Comment: Although, changing it to “Since last week, I have been working on this project.”  sounds correct.

Answer (score -1):

The first one is correct because explains a continuos action

The second one sounds like you’re working on it recently

Comment: The first is correct because of the function of present perfect continuous. The second one is bad grammar.